# Is it possible to spyOn (jest) multiple methods in same module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to spyOn more than one method in a typescript. How to achieve it in typescript?

```
// classA.ts
export class ClassA {
  public methodA() {
    this.methodB();
    this.methodC();
    return "ClassA";
  }
  public methodB() {}
  public methodC() {}
}

// classATest.ts
import {ClassA} from './classA';

it('Sample Test', async () => {
  const spyOn1 = jest.spyOn(ClassA, 'methodB');
    spyOn1.mockImplementation(() => {return () => {}});
    const spyOn2 = jest.spyOn(ClassA, 'methodC');
    spyOn2.mockImplementation(() => {return () => {}});

    const classA = new ClassA();
    expect(classA.methodA()).toEqual('ClassA');
});
```

I get error stating - `Argument of type '"methodC"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"methodB" | "prototype"'.`

Can't we use spyOn multiple methods on a class? Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to mock methods on either `ClassA.prototype` or `classA`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to spy on the `methodB` and `methodC` on `ClassA.prototype`. They are instance methods, **NOT** class static methods.

E.g.
`ClassA.ts`:

```js
export class ClassA {
  public methodA() {
    this.methodB();
    this.methodC();
    return 'ClassA';
  }
  public methodB() {}
  public methodC() {}
}
```

`ClassA.test.ts`:

```js
import { ClassA } from './classA';

describe('61315546', () => {
  it('Sample Test', async () => {
    const spyOn1 = jest.spyOn(ClassA.prototype, 'methodB');
    spyOn1.mockImplementation(() => {
      return () => {};
    });
    const spyOn2 = jest.spyOn(ClassA.prototype, 'methodC');
    spyOn2.mockImplementation(() => {
      return () => {};
    });

    const classA = new ClassA();
    expect(classA.methodA()).toEqual('ClassA');
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61315546/ClassA.test.ts (12.1s)
  61315546
    ✓ Sample Test (3ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 ClassA.ts |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.974s
```